# AG-Grid: How to hide values columns in pivot mode?

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

I have multiple columns with aggregation:

```
const gridOptions: GridOptions = {
  pivotMode: false,
  groupIncludeTotalFooter: true,
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'year', rowGroup: true },
    { field: 'month' },
    { field: 'col1', aggFunc: 'sum' },
    { field: 'col2', aggFunc: 'sum' },
};
```

But I when I enable pivot mode on year column, it shows both col1 and col2 for each year:

```
function enablePivotMode() {
  gridOptions.columnApi.setPivotMode(true);
  gridOptions.columnApi.setPivotColumns(['year']);
  gridOptions.columnApi.setRowGroupColumns(['month']);   
}
```

How to I select secondary columns to be visible in pivot mode?

Comment: Any luck with it? Could you achieve it?

Comment: was there a solution to this problem?

Comment: 2 years later... no answer, same problem.... The documentation is a mess IMO.

Answer (score 0):

To hide other columns you don't want in the pivot you need to set the `aggFunc` to `null`, e.g.

```
columnApi.applyColumnState({
    state: [
        { colId: 'col1', aggFunc: null }
    ]
});
```

NB You may also want to change your `columnDefs` to use `initialAggFunc` instead of `aggFunc` to avoid the column config being reset on new data.